# Android resource linked failed

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

I have changed package name in my application.

If I create android signed bundle it through the following error.

```
E:\JayVyas\CodeBase\Lapeno2\Lapeno\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\peerServerRelease\processPeerServerReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.lapeno_testing:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
E:\JayVyas\CodeBase\Lapeno2\Lapeno\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\peerServerRelease\processPeerServerReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.lapeno_testing:string/app_name) not found.
E:\JayVyas\CodeBase\Lapeno2\Lapeno\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\peerServerRelease\processPeerServerReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.lapeno_testing:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
E:\JayVyas\CodeBase\Lapeno2\Lapeno\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\peerServerRelease\processPeerServerReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:40: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.lapeno_testing:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
```

How can I resolve this issues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to clean and build your project?

Comment: Please paste your `manifest.xml`

Comment: @KaranMer
Yes I tried that stuff

Comment: is this resource available in the particular path?